Spring boot не находит файлы миграции Flyway
Столкнулся с непонятной ситуацией, при запуске проги в IntelejIDEA в сообщениях выводится инфа что не найдены файлы миграции Flyway, хотя все сделано корректно:

корретные имена формата VВерсия__Имя.sql

Расположены в db\migration


Делал тестовый пример, чтобы чисто в программе 1 файл миграции и ничего более - всё успешно работает
Почему не работает в основной программе непонятно
Пробовал делать миграцию в Постгрес, установленный на ПК и поднятый контейнер Докера
В обоих случаях соединение с БД устанавливается, таблица flyway_schema_history создается.
2024-04-03 11:42:41.875  INFO 9804 --- [           main] c.g.N.J.JavarushTelegramBotApplication   : Starting JavarushTelegramBotApplication using Java 19.0.2 on DESKTOP-CA807G7 with PID 9804 (C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\JavaRushTelegramBot\target\classes started by User in C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\JavaRushTelegramBot)
2024-04-03 11:42:41.877  INFO 9804 --- [           main] c.g.N.J.JavarushTelegramBotApplication   : The following 1 profile is active: "test"
2024-04-03 11:42:42.338  INFO 9804 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-04-03 11:42:42.393  INFO 9804 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 46 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-04-03 11:42:42.857  INFO 9804 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : Flyway Community Edition 8.5.13 by Redgate
2024-04-03 11:42:42.857  INFO 9804 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : See what's new here: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/releaseNotes#8.5.13
2024-04-03 11:42:42.857  INFO 9804 --- [           main] o.f.c.internal.license.VersionPrinter    : 
2024-04-03 11:42:42.863  INFO 9804 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-04-03 11:42:43.003  INFO 9804 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-04-03 11:42:43.040  INFO 9804 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.database.base.BaseDatabaseType   : Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/dev_jrtb_db (PostgreSQL 11.22)
2024-04-03 11:42:43.083  INFO 9804 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate     : Successfully validated 0 migrations (execution time 00:00.016s)
2024-04-03 11:42:43.084  WARN 9804 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate     : No migrations found. Are your locations set up correctly?
2024-04-03 11:42:43.114  INFO 9804 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.s.JdbcTableSchemaHistory         : Creating Schema History table "public"."flyway_schema_history" ...
2024-04-03 11:42:43.178  INFO 9804 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Current version of schema "public": << Empty Schema >>
2024-04-03 11:42:43.180  INFO 9804 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Schema "public" is up to date. No migration necessary.
2024-04-03 11:42:43.384  INFO 9804 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-04-03 11:42:43.492  INFO 9804 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.14.Final
2024-04-03 11:42:43.797  INFO 9804 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2024-04-03 11:42:44.024  INFO 9804 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2024-04-03 11:42:44.814  INFO 9804 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2024-04-03 11:42:44.824  INFO 9804 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-04-03 11:42:46.333  INFO 9804 --- [           main] c.g.N.J.JavarushTelegramBotApplication   : Started JavarushTelegramBotApplication in 4.812 seconds (JVM running for 5.536)


Буду очень признателен, кто укажет на ошибку, из-за которой не находит файлы миграции

Ссылка на гит
https://github.com/Naroru/JavaRushTelegramBot/tree/STEP_5_JRTB-1

Миграции должны находиться в корне проекта, а не в resources

Ничего подобного

Имхо, несколько странно прописать в pom, что в ресурсах должны быть только файлы .properties и ждать, что flyway найдет sql-скрипты :) Зачем вообще указывать фильтрацию ресурсов? И второе - перенесите файл application-test.properties в ресурсы тестов. Негоже впрямую иметь в "боевых" ресурсах логины-пароли и прочие секреты.

kami, спасибо огромное! Даже и не помню, когда туда внес фильтр по ресурсам.
По хранению боевых конфиденциальных данных -  конечно, это пока недоделано просто

Дело было в установленной фильтрации на ресурсы в pom.xml, файлы миграции из-за этого были невидны. Спасибо kami за найденную ошибку
